# Traceback error from python selenium script (Works intermittently)

Tags: python, linux, selenium, webdriver

I have written a selenium script in Python to automate posting to a particular website.  I have run it in the past, and it has worked flawlessly. However, i went to run the script and am now suddenly receiving the below. 
I believe it is a problem with the module loading somehow. In addition sometimes firefox will open and other times it won't.  Linux on a mac.

SCRIPT:

```
from selenium import webdriver
browser = webdriver.Firefox()
browser.get('https://losangeles.craigslist.org/')
```

ERROR:

```
/usr/bin/python2.7 /home/max/Desktop/CraigsList.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/max/Desktop/CraigsList.py", line 4, in <module>
    browser = webdriver.Firefox()
  File "/home/max/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/firefox/webdriver.py", line 81, in __init__
    self.binary, timeout)
  File "/home/max/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/firefox/extension_connection.py", line 51, in __init__
    self.binary.launch_browser(self.profile, timeout=timeout)
  File "/home/max/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/firefox/firefox_binary.py", line 68, in launch_browser
    self._wait_until_connectable(timeout=timeout)
  File "/home/max/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/firefox/firefox_binary.py", line 98, in _wait_until_connectable
    raise WebDriverException("The browser appears to have exited "
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: The browser appears to have exited before we could connect. If you specified a log_file in the FirefoxBinary constructor, check it for details.
```

Answer (score 0):

1. try run FF in console, with same user and path which you use for run python script
2. setup log_file for webdriver
3. maybe better use PhantomJS driver?